# Use boolean numpy array for indexing a list?

Tags: numpy

can anyone tell my what I am doing wrong?
I created an integer array from a boolean array but still cannot use it as an index for a list:

```
dataset = []
dataset.append({
                "a": "few",
                "b": "cd"
            })
dataset.append({
                "a": "fe",
                "b": "c"
            })
dataset.append({
                "a": "f",
                "b": "cwef"
            })

split = 0.5
# generate bolean mask
msk = np.random.rand(len(dataset)) < split 
print(msk)

# transform mask to int version
msk = np.where(msk)
print(msk)

# take only first part of touple as index mask
# ERROR:  only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
dataset_low = dataset[msk[0]] 
dataset_high = dataset[~msk[0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That magic only works with numpy arrays, `dataset` is a list.

You could convert it to a numpy array with a custom datatype.

And it only works if you don't use `np.where` and stick with a boolean array.

Negating `~` a result of `np.where` does not make sense, as the result are indices, not boolean values.

```
...
#msk = np.where(msk)
...

dataset = np.array(dataset)
dataset_low = dataset[msk[0]] 
dataset_high = dataset[~msk[0]]
....
```